# Unable to get YouTube auth BAHYouTubeOAuth iOS

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api, cocoapods

I am using BAHYouTubeOAuth in my iOS app. My code is:

```
[youTubeOAuth authenticateWithYouTubeUsingYouTubeClientID:Client_ID
                                          youTubeClientSecret:Client_Secret
                                                 responseType:@"code"
                                                        scope:@"https://gdata.youtube.com"
                                                        state:@""
                                               appURLCallBack:@"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
                                                   accessType:@"online"
```

When I use

```
appURLCallBack:@"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
```

this shows something like this

https://developers.google.com/accounts/images/installedresult.png

What should be the "state" and "appURLCallBack"?

Answer (score 0):

try to use State as BladerFeed & appURLCallBack as  http://localhost/oauth2callback